# Accessing S3 object using docker run command through Boto3, throws ProfileNotFound exceptions but works well when run through python

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, boto3, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am working on a project, where I need to read Text File from S3 bucket using Boto3. Then need to dockerize my application. I Implemented my code using Boto3, its running Perfectly fine(Note: Taking two arguments through argparser with switches -p and -n). But when I try the same using Docker run

```
PS **my Working Directory** > docker run --rm Image_name -p Argument1 -n Argument2

<class 'botocore.exceptions.ProfileNotFound'> Code.py 92
```

I searched lot of things on it, my understanding is AWS container directory is unable to locate my Credential File and config file stored in my home directory/.aws folder.

What I Tried:

**1.** Path mounting as below:

```
 PS **my Working Directory** > docker run --rm -it -v %userprofile%\.aws:/root/.aws 
 amazon/aws-cli
 docker: Error response from daemon: %!u(string=is not a valid Windows path)serprofile%!\ 
 (MISSING).aws.
```

See 'docker run --help'.

I completely don't understand what's wrong with the syntax. I tried manually inputting my user profile directory in the %userprofile% as C:/Users/Deepak

Then Strangely WSL2(backend) popup comes saying using passing containers on windows may poorly work.
I am not sure what it means. Does it have any effect on Docker containers build on windows environment?

**2.** I moved my Credential and Config file in my working directory as well and tried below code:

```
    PS my Working Directory > docker run --rm -it -v ${PWD}:/root/.aws amazon/aws-cli Image_name -p 
    Argument1 -n Argument2
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't see this earlier - It got bumped via someone's edit today.  Are you still looking for help with this?  If so, tag me in a reply so that I'll see your response.  I can see a few problems with your examples, but honestly, I won't spend a lot of time typing something up if you (a) aren't going to see it or (b) don't need it any longer.